# How to add an FTP user on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

#### (updated below)

I have SSH access to a Debian-based server, and I'm trying to add an FTP account on it. But I can't even get it to add it as a user in the first place. The command I've found that is supposed to solve this problem (for example let's call my user Steve), is this:

`useradd steve -p steves_password -g www-data -d /home/steve -s /bin/false`

The `-s /bin/false` part is supposedly Debian's way of saying not to allow Steve a shell (but regarding my problem explained below, I've tried it without that argument as well, with the same result).

After I execute it, I can see Steve in the `/etc/passwd` file. But if I try to log in as him directly, by doing `su steve`, it always says `su: Authentication failure`, even though I know the password is definitely correct, because I've changed it very carefully to try again, **and** I've changed it via `passwd steve` just to try.

Neither thing works; logging in directly on the shell via `su`, nor connecting via an FTP client program.

What I want is just a way to create FTP accounts to give people limited access to only the root folders of their corresponding subdomains.

## Update

I don't know what went wrong before, but I've removed the user, and repeated this procedure 3 times, and the 3rd time I did something right, because I can log in as Steve locally now.

But now I'm missing the functionality to allow steve to log in through an FTP client, that still doesn't go through.

Comment: What says `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for trying to help, after I was getting ready to paste it here, I've managed to log in actually... So that part goes through now. (but over FTP it still doesn't)

Comment: Then `/var/log/auth.log` (and the FTP server likely also has a log).